# How to do a proper upgrade in wix installer?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8, wix3.10

Currently I'm developing a wix installer (wix 3.10) and I need to provide upgrade capability to that. So I did the following.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="TestApp" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Abc" UpgradeCode="f27ec9f8-ddd0-403d-a1ca-5153e65c6471">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" AdminImage="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: $(var.ProductVersion)" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." Schedule="afterInstallExecute" /> </Product>
```

In here I keep Upgrade code and the Product Version same. Only changes the Product Code.

The problem in this is when I even do a small change to the code (eg: Adding a comment) it creates a new Product Code for the application and installs a new application even though there is a same version of the same application currently installed on the computer (Finally there will be two applications with same version and name on the computer).

My requirement is, I need to upgrade the existing version (Currently installed version on the computer) of the application if and only if the new application's version is higher than the existing version. If the versions are same then it should prompts the user that there is an application with same version.

Can anybody please tell me a way to achieve this. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: You should be getting your downgrade error message and not installing in this case. Can you run an "upgrade" with msi logging enabled and see what the logs say (msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.txt)? You should see a log line during FindRelatedProducts

PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property. Its value is '{Product GUID here}'. Or maybe it will be called WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED not sure.

Comment: Hey Brian, there is no  PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property in my msi logg file for the upgrading. But there is something like this instead. I wonder whether it has some thing to do with my issue. **FindRelatedProducts: could not read ASSIGNMENTTYPE info for product '{C94A3EB5-90BF-4F31-9F39-B299C28AAA7E}'.  Skipping...** This happens several times in the logg for different GUIDs. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: Would you be able to post the log on somewhere like pastebin.com? Also, are you testing your install in a clean environment? Typically this would be a VM that has a clean snapshot. You can get into some really messed up states when developing an installer if you keep installing and uninstalling (sometimes unsuccessfully) on the same system leaving the machine in a weird state.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem up to some extent. As I found out in the documentation, Wix let the installer to install two applications in the same machine if the product code is different in those two applications while the UpgradeCode and version number are same. This happened because the attribute "AllowSameVersionUpgrades=no" by default in MajorUpgrade element. By using the above code of mine I can upgrade the current application when I install a higher version than that. But the thing I couldn't done still is to prompt a message for the user when he/she installs a same version.

Comment: Ah yes the same version! I completely forgot about that. It makes total sense now. Another thing to remember is that Windows Installer considers 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.2 to be the same version since it ignores the last part of the version number. If you want real upgrades you always need to increase the first, second, or third part of the version. The reason you are seeing this behaviour is that you are only supposed to deploy one build of a version of the installer. If you want to test upgrades you must use two different versioned installs with matching upgrade code detection.

Comment: You should never deploy the same version of an installer twice. If you are properly incrementing the version between releases your upgrade should work fine.

There should only be one installer per version so you should never run into the issue of installing the same versioned different product ID installs in production only potentially in development.